# The classification of developable surfaces: Are these statements equivalent?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, surfaces, submanifold

I thought to know very well the answer to the classification problem for developable surfaces, so I sought for some confirmation in the literature. However, what I encountered are seemingly inequivalent statements that I am not sure how to interpret.

Recall that a smooth surface $S \subset \mathbb{R}^{3}$ is said to be *developable* if it is locally isometric to $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ (or, equivalently, if its Gaussian curvature vanishes).

First off, what I thought was true is the following statement, present for example in Pressley's *Elementary differential geometry*, 2nd edition, at page 203:

> If $S$ is developable, then it is the union of (generalized) cylinders, (generalized) cones, and tangent developables, joined together along segments of straight lines.

However, if one checks Do Carmo's *Differential geometry of curves and surfaces* (2nd edition, pp. 197–198), then one gets a seemingly different answer. After listing cylinders, cones, and tangent surfaces, he writes:

> "Of course, the above cases do not exhaust all possibilities. As usual, if there is a clustering of zeros of the functions involved, the analysis may become rather complicated. At any rate, away from these cluster points, a developable surface is a union of pieces of cylinders, cones, and tangent surfaces."

So he affirms that Pressley's claim is only valid ***away from cluster points***. The same conclusion is also drawn in Gray's *Modern differential geometry of curves and surfaces with Mathematica* (3rd edition, p. 448).

As if that weren't enough, another seemingly different statement is given in Kühnel's *Differential geometry. Curves—surfaces—manifolds* (3rd edition, p. 88):

> "An open and dense subset of every torse [= developable surface] consists of pieces of planes, cones, cylinders or tangent developable".

So my questions are the following. Are all these statements really equivalent? If so, why?

Comment: One difference seems to be that Pressley talks about smooth developable surfaces but Do Carmo just says developable.

Comment: Question cross-posted to MO (https://mathoverflow.net/q/413652/74033)